# Can I consolidate these two jQuery on() events with a toggle()?

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

There has got to be a way to do these in one toggleClass():

```
$('div').on("mouseenter", ".myButton", function(){
        $(this).addClass('rollOver');
    });
$('div').on("mouseleave", ".myButton", function(){
        $(this).removeClass('rollOver');
    });
```

...but it's within an on() because the myButton is created dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $('div').on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".myButton", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('rollOver');
    });
```

Comment: You should really use the switch argument for `.toggleClass()`. If the mouse pointer happens to be over the element when the handler is assigned, you'll end up with a reversed behavior. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZeAY8/). I've delayed the handler binding by 2 seconds. If you plant the pointer over the blue box within that time, and leave it there until the handler is assigned, you'll see that the behavior is reversed. *(Oh, and check your syntax.)* ;-)

Comment: ...oops, forget the *"check your syntax"* note from my previous comment. The comment was initially intended for @jfriend00's answer, but then he deleted it. But the *switch* argument part still stands.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('div').on("mouseleave mouseenter", ".myButton", function (e){
  $(this).toggleClass('rollOver', e.type == "mouseenter");
});
```

Comment: Nice exmaple.
THankz man...
vry much useful for me... :) +1 from myside... ;)